# A compact $n$-manifold is orientable iff there is an everywhere nonzero $n$-form

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

> Let $M$ be a compact differentiable manifold of dimension $n$ without boundary. Show that $M$ is orientable if and only if there exists a diffential $n$-form $\omega$ defined on $M$ and which is everywhere nonzero.

To show the "only if" part, I'm trying to use the fact that there exists a differentiable partition of unity on $M$, $\{\varphi_i\}_{i=1}^m$, where the support of $\varphi_i$ is contained in some $V_{\alpha_i}$ such that $\{V_{\alpha_i}\}_{i=1}^m$ is a covering of $M$. *($M$ is compact)

Hence, I'm trying to define $\omega$ a $n$-differential form which representation on $U_{\alpha_i}$ (such that $f_{\alpha_i}:U_{\alpha_i}\to V_{\alpha_i}$ is a parametrization of $M$) is given by 
$$\omega_{\alpha_i}=\varphi_i\,dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$$

I don't know if it's correct until this point. But, if it is, I can't show that $\omega$ is well defined, and I didn't use the fact that $M$ is orientable. Also, I have no idea how to show the "if" part.

Comment: Put a Riemannian metric on $M$. Then (thanks to the orientation) there is a well-defined volume form that takes an oriented orthonormal basis $e_i$ and spits out $\omega(e_1, \dots, e_n) = 1$. Use this form. It's a little strange that they ask for $M$ to have no boundary, since that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: As a suggestion: Your original title was "Let M be a compact differentiable manifold of dimension n without boundary."  It's not very helpful to just use the first sentence of your problem statement as a title; readers can't tell from that what your question is actually about.  (If everyone followed that, just think of the number of questions whose title would be "Let $p$ be a prime".)  It's also not good style to have the title contain information which is not also in the body.  I changed it to something that seems better to me, but you are welcome to make further edits.

Comment: @MikeMiller I didn't understand how this helps.

Comment: You started with an orientation and ended with a nonvanishing $n$-form.